# Postgresql - use of set-returning function in join

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that uses the output of a set-returning function in a join, but cant seem to uncover the correct syntax so am wondering if others have any suggestion?

I've a table column which contains data in the form of

```
{"manuscripts": [{"documentId": 39645, "journalAcronym": "MPB"}, {"documentId": 12123, "journalAcronym": "MPB"}]}
```

and want to use the documentId fields in a subsequent query. I can successfully extract the fields using a query along the lines of

```
select (jsonb_array_elements(manuscripts->'manuscripts')::json->>'documentId')::int from someTable
```

which produces

[image]

However, when I try and combine the results into a join condition of the form

```
join someOtherTable sot on someCondition
    and sot.document_id in ((jsonb_array_elements(manuscripts->'manuscripts')::json->>'documentId')::int)
```

I get the following error

[image]

Despite some googling around, I cant seem to uncover the syntax to convert a set into something I can use in the 'IN'. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any/all thoughts gratefully received...

Comment: Please share the tables definition either as a CTE expressions or as `CREATE TABLE` / `INSERT` queries.

Comment: You can create a JOIN against the relation returned by the function, but you cannot use the function in the JOIN *condition*. Use a subquery for that if you must (`… ON someCondition AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(…) WHERE …)`)

Comment: @bergi - your suggestion about using a subquery makes things work fine - thanks very much for that. If I'm reading your response correctly, then it sounds as though you think I'm doing something strange/sub-optimal...is there a better way of doing this sort of thing? I'm pretty new to postgesql so always keen to learn from others...

Comment: @PhilS I had missed the `IN` operator and didn't understand what you were trying to achieve, seeing the set-returning function in a condition was therefore really strange. I suppose it's fine what you are doing - until you need to join in the other direction, i.e. find a `someTable` row that relates to a particular `someOtherTable` row, as you'll have a hard time building an index to support search by manuscript document id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to avoid calling set-returning functions in a `SELECT` clause since they implicitly become a lateral join, which feels sneaky - better be explicit:

```
SELECT (m.el->>'documentId')::int AS document_id
FROM some_table t, LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.manuscripts->'manuscripts') AS m(el);
```

As you discovered, the implicit lateral join does not work in a `JOIN` condition (or `WHERE` clause, for that matter) - the expression needs to evaluated to a single boolean value, not a set of them.

In your case, you can either expand the set-returning function call to a separate join

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table t,
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.manuscripts->'manuscripts') AS m(el)
JOIN some_other_table sot ON … AND sot.document_id = (el->>'documentId')::int;
```

or use a subquery for the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table t
JOIN some_other_table sot ON … AND sot.document_id IN (
  SELECT (el->>'documentId')::int
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.manuscripts->'manuscripts') AS m(el)
);
```